# Custom context menu not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, contextmenu

I have a chat app built with NextJS and I'm trying to add a custom context menu to pin, favorite, or delete a message. Here's my code so far:

```js
const [isContextClicked, setIsContextClicked] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleContextMenu = async (event: MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement, globalThis.MouseEvent>) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  setIsContextClicked(true);
};

return (
  <div className='chat-message' onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}>
    ...
    {isContextClicked && (
      <CustomContextMenu ... />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

This works so far on computers - when I right-click the chat message, the custom context menu does display and I'm able to pin, favorite, or delete a message. Unfortunately, when I tried it on an iPhone by clicking and holding on a chat message, the custom context menu doesn't show up - the text gets selected and highlighted instead allowing me to copy etc. which I think is the default behavior for mobile.

I also tried:

```js
return (
  <div className='chat-message' onClick={handleContextMenu} onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}>
    ...
    {isContextClicked && (
      <CustomContextMenu ... />
    )}
  </div>
);
```

So that if I click on a chat message, the custom context menu would also show up, however I'm not sure why it doesn't work for both desktop and mobile devices. What changes do I need to make so that my custom context menu shows on both desktop (by right-click) and mobile (by clicking and holding)?